# Pygame - detect collision direction

Tags: python, pygame

So i started some kinda big pygame project, everything went more or less well.

But now i'm really stuck at how to detect the directions of collisions.

So i got my character (2d sidescroller), and a sprite group for the obstacles which are by now all rects. Now however collision detection works fine, but is, and if it is then how, it possible to detect on which side of the obstacle rects the character rect collides with it?

---

Addition in case someone [stumbles upon this question](https://xkcd.com/979/): The janky solution I ended up implementing used a "scaffolding" of four (invisible) lines per obstacle, one for each side. Once a collision with a specific obstacle was detected I looked up the four lines around the colliding rectangle in a dict and then went to check which of these lines was currently colliding with the player sprite. It kind of worked but the whole project was a mess anyway.

Comment: Get the coordinates of both objects and check how they are related. It depends on how fine an answer you want, but if you only think in say 1D, then if you know there's a collision, you can check the relation of their x coordinates to see which side of the obsticle is the character.

Comment: Btw, as this is your first question: you should read a bit about how to ask nice questions, i.e. post relevant code etc. It is a lot easier to help, if people actually know what you need help with :)

Comment: @fbence thanks for the reply, tho how can i get the specific obstacle which collided out of the group?

Comment: @fbence Sure,  i just couldn't think of any code parts that would've been to helpful

Comment: Maybe part of you code that defines the obsticles, and the part that detects the collision might be useful. There are a few methods that can do this in pygame. Also, if you think that the comments are narrowing down your actual question (i.e. you are really interested in gettting which object the collision occured with etc.) you can edit your question.

Comment: @fbence oh okay. Thanks for that as well

Comment: Why do you actually need the side of the collision?

Comment: @skrx to know which movement it affects, if it collides to the right, this would stop the x movement, whereas from above it would stop the y movement

Comment: The simplest solution (but not most efficient) is to move the player along the x-axis first, check if he collides with an obstacle and move him back if he does, and then do the same for the y-axis.

Answer (score 3):

There are many 2D physics libraries that including collision detection and usually a large project like you said would require other physics like constraints, ray casting and bodies. A great library for python is pyBox2D and has good documentation on their [github](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/wiki/manual). pyBox2D will also fully handle collisions for you but you can also setup custom collision handlers.
For you question you ask how to check which position a rect collides with, you can do this using the pygame.Rect variables that are given like so

```
import pygame


def determineSide(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.midtop[1] > rect2.midtop[1]:
        return "top"
    elif rect1.midleft[0] > rect2.midleft[0]:
        return "left"
    elif rect1.midright[0] < rect2.midright[0]:
        return "right"
    else:
        return "bottom"

rect1 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 20, 20)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(100, 90, 20, 20)
print(determineSide(rect1, rect2))
```

Note this does not check for collision but simply checks where rect2 is relative to rect1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check which one or two of the four corners on one `Rect` are inside the other. There is one problem, though - if the `Rect`s are touching by the corners, it's up to the rest of the program what to do then. I haven't written a code snippet for this myself, but I'm working on a platformer as well and plan to create one.